# Azure AD B2B Invite new user in security group, not O365 group

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2b

When sending invites to new users using the Azure B2B invite API, the new users are getting created into Office 365 groups but we want to have them in security groups.

We are following the process demonstrated in this link:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/09/29/getting-started-with-the-azure-ad-b2b-invite-api/

creating an invitation by posting to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations.

The users who accept the invitation are showing up as below:
[image]

we need these users to be in security groups, not O365 groups. Anyone know the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Microsoft Graph to add a user to a group (even a guest user to a security group).  Here's how:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_post_members

Hope this helps,